# How do I change the source of an image loaded in a custom JQuery script?

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I'm trying to modify a JQuery Slider to replace the big image by another one depending on the user: If he hovers over a small image, it will be loaded in a bigger format.

So at some point in the script I have the load image process :

```
// call this function after it's loaded
        img.onload = function() {

            // make wrapper fully visible
            wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

            // change the image
            wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);

        };

        // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
        img.src = url;
```

But what I am trying to do here is change the orginal src, by adding some characters to the src url, so that when the user hovers over an image, another one is loaded in the slider instead (related to the small one of course).

For instance, if I have product1.jpg in the small boxes, and the user hovers over it, I would like to load product1Big.jpg in the slider.

Here is the full script :

```
        $(function() {
        $(".scrollable").scrollable();

        $(".items img").hover(function() {
            // see if same thumb is being clicked
            if ($(this).hasClass("active")) { return; }

            // calclulate large image's URL based on the thumbnail URL (flickr specific)
            var url = $(this).attr("src").replace("_t", "");

            // get handle to element that wraps the image and make it semi-transparent
            var wrap = $("#image_wrap").fadeTo("medium", 0.5);

            // the large image from www.flickr.com
            var img = new Image();


            // call this function after it's loaded
            img.onload = function() {

                // make wrapper fully visible
                wrap.fadeTo("fast", 1);

                // change the image
                wrap.find("img").attr("src", url);

            };

            // begin loading the image from www.flickr.com
            img.src = url;

            // activate item
            $(".items img").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

        // when page loads simulate a "click" on the first image
        }).filter(":first").click();
    });
```

Comment: This just looks like a copy-paste of the tutorial code on http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/gallery.html So, what have you tried to get the different paths working?

Comment: Well for now, I can't make it working, I've tried wrap.find("img").attr("src", url.'big'); but it doesn't seems towork that way . And Yes you're right, it may have been taken from jquerytools, I took it from an old website of mine, didn't remember where I got it first.

Comment: `wrap.find("img").attr("src", url.'big');` should instead be `wrap.find("img").attr("src", url+'big');` - in JS `+` is the concatenation operator.

Comment: thank you, but how could I get rid of the .jpg since I have get rid of it, add the 'big' and '.jpg' ? I know how to do it in php with substr, I guess there is a similar function with JQuery